# struct does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]

Tags: c, struct, syntax

I was trying to make a camera struct to handle a camera for an openGL tutorial in C.

```c
// camera.h
#ifndef CAMERA_H
#define CAMERA_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <cglm/cglm.h>

struct camera
{
    bool ortho;
    float ratio;
    vec3 pos, x, y, z;
    float fov, yaw, pitch, roll;
    mat4 view, projection, model;
};

int updateCamera(struct camera *c);

#endif
```

but when I compile (with clang) i get these two errors:

```
./src/visual/camera.h:7:1: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
struct camera
^
./src/visual/camera.h:16:5: error: field 'updateCamera' declared as a function
int updateCamera(struct camera *c);
    ^
```

I do not understand what is wrong with the declared struct (the same errors appear for any other struct in the same file)

my guess would be that something is wrong in another file, but I do not know what to search, plus there aren't any included files

If somebody could give me any hint about what could be wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!

*sry for my english & still beginner understanding of C*

Comment: I don't know much about OpenGL, as well as the causes of the problem that you're getting. Maybe just try to replace the `struct`'s name from `camera` to something else, and then see if it works.

Comment: What is the compilation command you are using?

Comment: Look at the preprocessed output.  I think you'll find that some word — possibly `camera` — is defined as a macro.  You may be running into some other problem.  Assuming `vec3` comes from `cglm/cglm.h`, try removing that `#include` and the `vec3 pos, x, y, z;` line and see whether it works better.  Similarly with the `mat4` line.  The 'member declared as function' message seems to imply that `};` at the end of the structure is not being recognized, or there's an `{` that isn't being closed properly, or something.  It's a bit weird.  You shouldn't be running into the problem from what we see.

Comment: Can you compile a file containing `#include <cglm/chlm.h>` and `vec3 x3;` (only)?  If not, the problem is hidden in the header.  If you use GCC, you might add `-dM` to see the list of defined macros (as well as using `-E` to see the preprocessed output).  That may reveal the source of the trouble.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code you posted, and clang compiled it for me with no errors or warnings. The issue must be related to something else that you haven't shown us. C compilation is a little weird in that the file and line number it gives an error or warning on is often not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After trying out everything that came to my mind, I finally found the answer:

I had another file (`global.h`) in which I included the `camera.h`file. I have the habit to put `#include` just before the part of the code that requires tha specific file, to help me track my dependecies. Here it seemed to generate that problem because once I moved the `#include "visual/camera.h"` to the top of the file, the errors magically went away.
`global.h` before

```c
struct game_state
{
    float delta_time;
    float speed;

    #include "window/glfw.h"
    struct window window;
    #include "visual/camera.h"
    struct camera camera;
};
struct game_state state;
```

`global.h` after the change, resolving the problem

```c
#include "window/glfw.h"
#include "visual/camera.h"

struct game_state
{
    float delta_time;
    float speed;

    struct window window;
    struct camera camera;
};
struct game_state state;
```

I still do not understand what was wrong but hey, it works.

*Thanks to everybody's answer, u made me learn new things !*

Comment: `#include` directives work by essentially copying the code from the included file at the point the `#include` appears.  This resulted in declaring a struct in another struct causing the warning, and declaring a function inside the struct causing the error.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the problem is that you are using C++ syntax in a C file.
Try this:

............

```
typedef struct
{
    bool ortho;
    float ratio;
    vec3 pos, x, y, z;
    float fov, yaw, pitch, roll;
    mat4 view, projection, model;
} tCamera;

int updateCamera(tCamera *c);
```

............